# Processmaker Cases Finish In Draft Folder instead of going to Inbox of next assigned User - ProcessMaker

Tags: processmaker

Processmaker - Cases Finish In Draft Folder instead of going to Inbox of next assigned User
After the next user is assigned and I click continue, it goes to the next user as set in assignment rules but instead of going to their Inbox it rather goes to participated and the status of the case is set to Draft.

I'm using the community version of the application. I'm not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the Processmaker Queue service needs starting, I had that problem on a bitnami download for AWS. The latest Processmaker uses Laravel queues. See https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/processmaker-administration/queue-management